# how can i execute other class?

Tags: java, execution

i have to connect java to mysql db using jdbc. thats not a problem and i can query data from db successfully. the problem is, i have another class that i need to execute which the application is using the data from db. can i execute jdbc and call the application class to executed after the data dragged from db?means, i just execute jdbc class in command prompt and automatically application class also executed

Comment: this should be obvious. but the reason you posted this question makes me think that there is something unique with the way application class works. post a sample of the application class

Answer (score 0):

The class without main will be a part of the library. (.jar)
You can call the function in the application class.(even main) But this will not start the application as the application will start only when JVM calls main on the application class and loads it into its memory!
Can suggest you an alternative way to do it, if you give some more details.

Comment: i have con.java.in this class, i connect to db and query data.then i have app.java.this class need to use data thet i query in con.java before.u mean, i just call function main from app.java in con.java?

Comment: Ensure that the 2 classes are in the same package.

Comment: If just function call is needed. Con.java: Write a function (static if you are not using an object of Con.java in App.java) which will return a resultset for the query that it runs. Or the function can be written such that it returns an object (can be a list too).  App.java: If the function in con class is static, u can directly call Con.XYZ() and accept the resultset or object (or list) in an function. If the function XYZ is not static, make an object of Con class and use it to call XYZ.